# What event do I hook into to dispose of IDisposable items in the ASP.NET *Request* cache?

Tags: asp.net

Lets imagine a class

```
class Foo: IDisposable
{
 Dispose()
 {
   //Dispose of nonmanged resources.
 }
}
```

Let image that a use case exist for putting it into `HttpContext.Items`.  It doesn't automatically raise errors when you add an object that implement IDisposable (and who knows, maybe the answer is that it should)

What event(s) do I need to hook into to dispose of that item?

Lets also assume that using blocks are not available as the object gets used into two different method blocks.

Comment: `Application_EndRequest`, that is probably the last time you may need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Jaroslav Jandek, I think hooking into `Application_EndRequest` in global.asax would work just fine.  You can do a simple check to see if the item is preset in `HttpContext.Items` and if it is then dispose of it.

```
    protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["test"] = new IDisposableObject();
    }

    protected virtual void Application_EndRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("test")) {
            ((IDisposable)HttpContext.Current.Items["test"]).Dispose();
        }

    }
```